# When I run the debugger: "failed to set controlling terminal"

Tags: 16.04, permissions, debugging, gdb

In a book I read, the author's CPU was 32-bit. Mine is 64-bit. I run the NASM assembler in the terminal with:

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs asmwork/eatsyscall.asm
```

Then I run the linker:

```
ld -o eatsyscall eatsyscall.o
```

This returned:

ld: i386 architecture of input file `eatsyscall.o` is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

I read some answers and it said I needed to use `elf64` (not as the book said).
I run the assembler and it solved this message.

Now I run in the terminal `kdbg eatsyscall.o`. It opens the KDbg software and *KDbg: Program output*.

I select a breakpoint in a line and as usual a red circle appears. I click run and the red circle is not changed for an arrow. Instead in the *KDbg: Program output* it outputs this message (I'm not showing where the `.o` file is as in the output it is written):

```
warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted 
/bin/bash: Permission denied 
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: cannot execute: Permission denied.
```

Or on one occasion, just this message:

```
warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted
```

---

In **Settings > Global Options** I have the following.

- How to invoke GDB: `gdb --fullname --nx`
- Terminal for program output: `xterm -name kdbgio -title %T -e sh -c %C`

---

What can I do? Why do I get a permission error? Is it something related to the command `sudo`?

---

**UPDATE**

For running the debugger I have used `kdbg program` and `kdbg ./program`.
The executable file I want to debug is called `program` and it is located in the folder `asmwork`. When my working directory is with that folder, I write `ls -l` and I get the following about the file:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 1304 יול 24 17:56 program
```

[image: this]

[image: this]

Comment: Can you open the kdbg [Global Options](http://www.kdbg.org/manual/globaloptions.html) dialog and post the exact command strings that it's using to (a) invoke gdb and (b) invoke the terminal emulator please?

Comment: @steeldriver Edited the question including your request.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is old. However, it is unanswered and it is receiving significant views, hence…..

> I read some answers and it said I needed to use `elf64` (not as the book said).

The book in question is really about programming in assembly language for Intel’s 32-bit x86  CPU’s, this is explicitly stated throughout, and in any of the marketing literature that I have seen. You’ll need to be mindful of subtle differences between the IA-32 and x86-64 architectures. If you are using a x86-64 PC, it stands to reason that some of the examples given in the text may need tweaking slightly.

In addition to changing `elf` to `elf64`, it would be wise to replace `stabs` with `dwarf`, as in my experience, assembling your program with `stabs` in x86-64 is not entirely compatible; stabs would be a more appropriate format for working with IA-32 Linux.

Again, it is up to you to decipher where the examples given in the text need adjusting for the change in technology.

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs eatsyscall.asm
```

becomes...............

```
nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf eatsyscall.asm
```

This should successfully compile your source code into a x86-64 compatible object code file.
...................................................................................................................................................................

Using `elf` format as opposed to `elf64`, will assembly a `x86` object code file. You can then create a 32-bit executable using the following:

`ld -m elf_i386 -o executablename objectfilename.o`

Option `-m` is for Emulation (please see `ld` man pages). Here you can select your desired architecture, from those available. Using `-m elf_i386` enables us to create a `i386` executable on our x86-64 machine.

You can use option `-V` to get a list of available architectures; please see man pages for full details.

..............................................................................

> I run in the terminal `kdbg eatsyscall.o`. It opens the Kdbg software and Kdbg: Program output

You will need to load an executable file into the debugger, not an object code file as above. You have already created this executable, assuming it was successful, when you ran the object module through the linker; as stated in your question.

Your main concern appears to be with the *warning* in the output terminal window.

The solution can be sought in the [manual](http://kdbg.org/manual/pgmoutput.html). I’ll reproduce the solution here, in case the URL fails in future.

> When a program is debugged with KDbg for the first time, the program
> output window is not used. The reason for this is that KDbg cannot know
> whether the program requires sophisticated terminal emulation or if it
> expects input through a terminal. So, a terminal emulator program is used
> by default. In order to redirect the output to the output window, you must
> do the following:
>
> 1. Open the Settings dialog by selecting Settings|This Program.
> 2. Switch to the Output tab.
> 3. Choose Only output, simple terminal emulation and click OK.
> 4. Reload the program by selecting it from the list in File|Recent >
>    Executables.